# Creating and Updating .Edmx file at runtime

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am creating a new table at runtime in MVC C# and then I need to add that very table to my .edmx file which is already present in my solution. I just need to Update and add that table in edmx file and do all sort of changes we need to have when we do update at RUNTIME. I hope if there is some way we can do that at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.edmx file does not exist at runtime. It's only used at design time to describe the model, the database and the mapping between the two. At runtime only the generated classes exist.

Comment: So, if you made a class for the table you were going to create at runtime, would you be able to reference it as a table in the database (assuming you put all the right tags in the class)?